# In win32 programming, If I create another top level window, do I need a separate window procedure for it?

Tags: winapi

I've run into an issue in my application that creates several top level windows (besides the main window):

The issue is that if I close any of the top level windows, my main window also closes. It took me several days to understand what was happening and I think I got it. It looks like the other top level windows use the same window procedure that my main window uses, as a result when I close any of the top level windows, the window procedure receives the `WM_CLOSE` message and that shuts down the whole application.

Therefore I've a question - if I create a new top level window, do I need to register a new class and associate a new window procedure for it?

Comment: No need for a separate proc. An efficient troubleshooting measure you can take is to run Spy++ tool and to check what exactly messages your other windows receive, that make other windows close when you don't expect it.

Comment: @RomanR. Thanks I'll try it right now. One question though - Is it true that if I don't specify a new windows procedure for my new windows, the main window's procedure gets used?

Comment: `CreateWindow` takes class name as parameter, and class/`WNDCLASS` has a `lpfnWndProc` attached - this is where window proc comes from. It does not matter whether it's already used by another window or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your window proc is presumably responding to WM_DESTROY by calling PostQuitMessage. Which brings the process down. You should only call PostQuitMessage when the main window closes. You can do this from a shared window procedure so long as you discriminate using the window handle that is handling the WM_DESTROY message.

Comment: That's it! WM_DESTROY was calling PostQuitMessage, which made the whole app to quit. I made PostQuitMessage conditional and now my app works. Thank you!